# JavaScript: Cannot read property direction of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, phaser-framework, pacman

I am creating a Pacman game in JavaScript using the following tools.

- **Phaser**: A JavaScript game library
- **Tiled**: For creating the tile maps

In my main update loop, I have a function that moves the ghosts. It starts off like this

```
moveGhosts: function() {
    ghosts.forEachExists(function(ghost) {

        if (ghost.y <= 210) {
            ghost.mobilized = true;
        }

        if (ghost.mobilized) {

            var ghostX = Math.round(ghost.x / map.tileWidth);
            var ghostY = Math.round(ghost.y / map.tileHeight);
```

I update the X and Y coordinates of the ghosts on every loop.

In Phaser, tilemaps are measured in tiles instead of pixels. To get the tile position, simply divide the x and y coordinates by the width and height of the tilemap respectively.

There are four possible directions in which Pacman can move

- Up
- Down
- Left
- Right

I thought the best data structure to store these possible moves would be an array of objects. Each move has the following properties

- **Direction:** This is one of the four directions listed above
- **Position:** This isn't used except for simplifying the next property
- **Distance:** This is the distance the ghost is from Pacman's position. To find the distance, I used the distance formula.
- **Available:** This determines whether the given move is valid. That is, if there is a path open along that direction.

Here is the array. My guess is that the problem lies somewhere in here.

```
var moves = [
                {
                    'direction': 'left',
                    'position': map.getTileLeft(0, ghostX, ghostY).x,
                    'distance': Math.sqrt(Math.pow((map.getTileLeft(0, ghostX, ghostY).x - pacmanX), 2) + 
                    Math.pow((map.getTileLeft(0, ghostX, ghostY).y - pacmanY), 2)),
                    'available': levelState.pathLeftAvailable(ghostX, ghostY)
                },
                {
                    'direction': 'right',
                    'position': map.getTileRight(0, ghostX, ghostY).x,
                    'distance': Math.sqrt(Math.pow((map.getTileRight(0, ghostX, ghostY).x - pacmanX), 2) + 
                    Math.pow((map.getTileRight(0, ghostX, ghostY).y - pacmanY), 2)),
                    'available': levelState.pathRightAvailable(ghostX, ghostY)
                },
                {
                    'direction': 'up',
                    'position': map.getTileAbove(0, ghostX, ghostY).y,
                    'distance': Math.sqrt(Math.pow((map.getTileAbove(0, ghostX, ghostY).x - pacmanX), 2) + 
                    Math.pow((map.getTileAbove(0, ghostX, ghostY).y - pacmanY), 2)),
                    'available': levelState.pathUpAvailable(ghostX, ghostY)
                },
                {
                    'direction': 'down',
                    'position': map.getTileBelow(0, ghostX, ghostY).y,
                    'distance': Math.sqrt(Math.pow((map.getTileBelow(0, ghostX, ghostY).x - pacmanX), 2) + 
                    Math.pow((map.getTileBelow(0, ghostX, ghostY).y - pacmanY), 2)),
                    'available': levelState.pathDownAvailable(ghostX, ghostY)
                }
            ];
```

I chose an array because this data needs to be filtered to show only legal moves and then sorted based on distance. The following two variables show

- The move that places the ghost closest to Pacman (Used when the red ghost is chasing Pacman)
- The move that places the ghost furthest from Pacman (Used when the ghost is vulnerable)

The variables

```
var closestTile = moves.filter(m => m.available).sort((a,b) => a.distance - b.distance)[0].direction;
var furthestTile = moves.filter( m => m.available).sort((a,b) => b.distance - a.distance)[0].direction;
```

This is where I receive the error message. **Can't read property direction of undefined**

Here is the rest of the function where these variables are put in play. The problem likely doesn't lie here, but this was added to show these variables in context.

```
this.game.physics.arcade.collide(ghost, wallLayer, function() {

    var ghostDirection;

    if (ghost.direction == 'up' || ghost.direction == 'down') {
        ghost.y += ghost.direction == 'up' ? 1 : -1;

        if (ghost.vulnerable) {
            ghostDirection = furthestTile;
        }

           else {
                 if (ghost == redGhost) {
                     ghostDirection = closestTile;
                 }

                 else {
                     ghostDirection = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'left' : 'right';
                 }
             }

             ghost.body.velocity.y = 0;
             ghost.body.velocity.x = ghostDirection == 'left' ? -ghostVelocity : ghostVelocity;
            }

            else if (ghost.direction == 'left' || ghost.direction == 'right') {
                ghost.x += ghost.direction == 'left' ? 1 : -1;

                if (ghost.vulnerable) {
                    ghostDirection = furthestTile;
                }

                else {

                    if (ghost == redGhost) {           
                        ghostDirection = closestTile;
                    }

                    else {
                        ghostDirection = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'up': 'down';
                    }
                }

                ghost.body.velocity.x = 0;
                ghost.body.velocity.y = ghostDirection == 'up' ? -ghostVelocity : ghostVelocity;
            }

            ghost.direction = ghostDirection;
        }, null, this);
```

Here are the four functions that determine whether a move is legal. The problem most likely doesn't lie here.

**Tiled** creates tile maps that are composed of layers

My game has a **Wall Layer** which shows the walls. This layer has an index of 0. If there are no walls blocking a path, then the move is legal. Sorry if this confused some people.

```
pathRightAvailable: function(x, y) {
        return [x, x + 1, x + 2].every(function(xPosition) {
            return !map.hasTile(xPosition, y, 0);
        });
    },

    pathLeftAvailable: function(x, y) {
        return [x, x - 1, x - 2].every(function(xPosition) {
            return !map.hasTile(xPosition, y, 0);
        });
    },

    pathUpAvailable: function(x,y) {
        return [y, y - 1, y - 2].every(function(yPosition) {
            return !map.hasTile(x, yPosition, 0);
        });
    },

    pathDownAvailable: function(x,y) {
        return [y, y + 1, y + 2].every(function(yPosition) {
            return !map.hasTile(x, yPosition, 0);
        });
    },
```

Here are some results of logging variables to the console.

```
console.log(moves)
=>
0:Object
available:true
direction:"left"
distance:35.4682957019364
position:26
__proto__:Object
1:Object
available:true
direction:"right"
distance:34.20526275297414
position:28
__proto__:Object
2:Object
available:true
direction:"up"
distance:35.608987629529715
position:36
__proto__:Object
3:Object
available:false
direction:"down"
distance:34.058772731852805
position:38
__proto__:Object
length:4
__proto__:Array(0)

console.log(closestTile)
=> 'down'
```

If you can solve this, good luck. I've been stuck on this problem for an hour.

Comment: Apparently none of the moves is available.

Comment: I am almost certain available isn't false for all moves. I think it would be a good idea for me to upload an image of my tile map. In the mean time, I will work on improving this question

Comment: Why do your pathAvailable functions do `!map.hasTile`? Surely the path is available if there *are* map tiles in the direction of the move, not if there *aren't*.

Comment: Just do `console.log(moves).`

Comment: Wait- `console.log(closestTile)` gives you a direction? So are you not getting the `undefined` error anymore? You said the error was in the line that creates `closestTile`. So what's the problem?